# Referencing common array in multiple mappings

Tags: solidity, blockchain, arrays, mapping

Trying to understand memory in blockchain for sharing reference of array as common storage for multiple mappings.

Let's say there is a need for following relationships.
So there will be products keep created and added into the products array.
I would like to create mapping of the product with some key in uint256 and also mapping for the customer to products relationship, shown below.

```
Product[] Products;
mapping(uint256 => Product) ProductsMap;
mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => Product) CustomerProductsMap;
```

So let's say there was new product created with unique id in uint256,

```
uint256 Id = 1;
Product memory newProduct =  Product({
   id: Id,
   name: "toy",
   price: 100000
});
```

And we add this to array, for quick GET external function.

```
Products.push(newProduct);
```

And we add key-val pair for quick look up, such that:

```
ProductsMap[Id] = newProduct;
```

And now, I would like to create customer - product relationship using the same instance.

```
CustomerProductsMap[customerAddress][Id] = newProduct;
```

So here is the question,
When the value of newProduct updated such that:

```
ProductsMap[1].price = 200000
```

Can I assume that this product's price now changed regardless of which map / array I use to look up?  I hope they all referencing to same memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you have created three copies of the same data.

Can't recommend something for this case but usually having a mapping from `ID` to `Product` and storing `ID` instead of `Product`.

Comment: yeah I figured out.. oh well seems mappings can't pass references.